# MVC Entity relationship - how to add child to entity as it's being created

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a BasinPeak entity with a default controller created in an MVC project.  When I open http://XX.XX.XX.XX:51573/BasinPeak/Create and add a new BasinPeak, how can I attach a new Note to the BasinPeak at this time?

I want to call the Create action from the NoteController but when the new Note was created how could I then pass the NoteId back to the BasinPeak?

Or is there a much easier way to add the Note and have it linked to the BasinPeak

```
public class BasinPeak
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public DateTime DateTime { get; set; }

    public int Edus { get; set; }

    public int Rating { get; set; }

    public int? NoteId { get; set; }

    public virtual Note Note { get; set; }
}   

public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public String Notes { get; set; }

    public DateTime When { get; set; }

    public String PersonId { get; set; }

    public String History { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Create the BasicPeak. Then at the View for Note creation ask for a basicpeak id were the user wants to add the note. You'll receive both in the controller, the note and the basic peak id. Get the basic peak by id and set the note

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you should ideally create a Basin Peak First and then create a note attached to that BasinPeak
if you want the user should not leave the page where the BasinPeak was created then try using ajax which ideally should be like this.

```
you hit url BasinPeak/Create<br>
form loaded to create basin peak
you fill in the values and hit submit
send request using ajax (try using juery form ajax)
if the creation of the BasinPeak is successfull return true with id of the recently created BasinPeak.
show him the markup to create a form. because now you have id of the created BasinPeak you can send another request to add the note to the created BasinPeak.
```

Still if you want to create then in one go then. you can try creating a seperate view model. containing values of the BasinPeak to be created and the values of the note to be created. Make the View strongly type to this View Model and create the Peak and the Note accordingly